# How to create an event in a user's Google Calendar that can not be modified?

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to create an event in a user's Google Calendar that can't be modified by that user.

In the following example, the API belongs to **a@gmail.com**, and is used to put an event in the calendar of **b@occsn.com**. To create an event that might be locked, I use the `import` interface from Google's API

```
start: 
  datetime: <date + time>      
end: 
  datetime: <date + time>
summary: My Awesome Event
i_cal_uid: <random UUID>
organizer:
  email: noreply@example.com   # Non-existent address
  display_name: MyAwesomeCompany
attendees:
  -
    email: <target calendar ID, e.g. user.com_q23rlj3we@group.calendar.google.com>
    response_status: accepted
```

This creates an event on the user's calendar. If the user sees it in his calendar app (I use *Fantastical*), it can't be moved, but if user goes to Google Calendar's web site directly, the event can be moved, and it warns – only once – about "only moving it in Target Calendar" or something.

My question: Is it possible to create an event in the user's calendar that the user can not modify or move at all?

Comment: I think this is not possible, because if you are the owner of the calendar, you will have a power that can edit/delete all the events inside your calendar.

Comment: Deleting is fine, of course. It would be ridiculous to not be able to delete things from your own calendar. :) But I do like the immovable character of shared events, at least as intended with the standard (IIRC), and I'm wondering if Google has a way to have those immovable.